# How to Update Matplotlib Legend After Calling add_artist

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am looking to update the properties of a matplotlib legend after it has been added to the axis using add_artist. In this example I have a legend called First Legend that contains only Line 1. After adding it to the axis by calling ax.add_artist(first_legend) I then add a second legend. At this point is it possible to make changes to First Legend and say add Line 3 as well?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
(line1,) = ax.plot([1, 2, 3], label="Line 1", linestyle="--")
(line2,) = ax.plot([3, 2, 1], label="Line 2", linewidth=4)
(line3,) = ax.plot([2, 2, 2], label="Line 3", linestyle="-")

# Create a legend for the first line.
first_legend = ax.legend(title="First Legend", handles=[line1], loc="upper right")

# Add the legend manually to the Axes.
first_legend_artist = ax.add_artist(first_legend)

# Create another legend for the second line.
second_legend = ax.legend(title="First Legend", handles=[line2], loc="lower right")

# Add Line 3 to first_legend after first_legend has been added as an artist
first_legend.set(handles=[line1, line3], loc="upper right")

plt.show()
```

I have tried using first_legend.set() as well as first_legend_artist.set() however none of them seem to contain the 'handles' attribute.